# GMOD Lua - Add ENT:Draw Hook to Existing Entity?

Tags: lua, hook

In Gmod Lua, how could I add a ENT:Draw hook for a specific entity which already exists on the map? Such as a door?﻿

I have tried the following code:

```
door.Draw = function()
    self:DrawModel()
    ChatPrint("Hi")
end
```

Which doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this question was asked a while ago, but I'm going to post here anyways for anyone else who has this question in the future.

The short answer is: You can't.

If it were to be possible, you'd do it through something called 'Entity Callbacks'

Available ones can be found here: http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Entity_Callbacks
More details on Entity callbacks found here: http://wiki.garrysmod.com/page/Entity/AddCallback